# Measure of similarity/disimilarity between LoG images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

This might be a very broad question so *I'm sorry* in advance. I'd like to also point out I'm new in the CV field, so my insight in this field is minimum.

I am trying to find correspondences between points from a FLIR image and a VIS image. I'm currently building 40x40 pixels regions around keypoints, over which I'm applying the LoG. I'm trying to compare them to find the most similar regions.

For example, I have these data sets:

[image: Dataset]

[image: Dataset]

Where the columns represent, in this order:

- the image for which I'm trying to find a correspondent
- the candidate images
- the LoG of the first column
- the LoG of the second column

It is very clear, for the human eye, that the third image is the best match for the first set, while the first image is the best image for the second set.

I have tried various ways of expressing a similarity/disimilarity between these images, such as SSD, Cross Correlation, or Mutual Information, but they all fail to be consistent (they only work in some cases).

Now, my actual question is:

What should I use to express the similarity between images in a more *semantic* way, such that shapes would be more important in deciding the best match, rather than actual intensities of the pixels? Do you know of any technique that would aid me in my quest of finding these matches?

Thank you!

**Note**: I'm using OpenCV with Python right now, but the programming language and library is not important.

Comment: Mutual information is the typical solution to this problem.